# XSLT delete inside <g> element of an

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, svg

I have some svg code that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
<g id="outer">
    <g id="inner-1">
        <defs>
               <rect/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath></clipPath>
        <polygon/>
    </g>
       <text>Some</text>
       <text>Text</text>
    <g id="inner-2">
        <defs>
               <rect/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath></clipPath>
       <polygon/>
   </g>
       <text>Some</text>
       <text>Text</text>
       <text>Some</text>
       <text>Text</text>
    <g id="inner-3">
        <defs>
               <rect/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath></clipPath>
       <polygon/>
   </g>
  <text>Keep this text</text>
  <text>Keep this text</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

How do I delete the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of the inner `<g>` tags and the `<text>` tags after the 1st inner `<g>`, and the `<text>` tags after the 2nd inner `<g>` tag. I could have nth many `<text>` tags after a `<g>`tag, but I will always "delete" (not selecting by over-riding the identity transformation) the 2nd inner `<g>` tag and the text that comes before that, and the 3rd inner `<g>` tag and the text that comes before that. 
I only want 1st occurrence of the inner'' tag and the `<text>` tag(s) that follow the 3rd occurrence of the inner '' tag. It should like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
<g id="outer">
    <g id="inner-1">
        <defs>
               <rect/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath></clipPath>
        <polygon/>
    </g>
  <text>Keep this text</text>
  <text>Keep this text</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

<!-- I don't know how to select preceding text -->
<xsl:template match="/svg/g/g[2]"/>
<!-- I don't know how to select preceding text -->
<xsl:template match="/svg/g/g[3]"/>
</stylesheet>
```

I tried using this code to transform the text elements following the 3rd `<g>` tag:

```
<xsl:template match="svg:text">
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="(following::svg:g[3])[parent::svg:g]">
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise/>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

...And that didn't work.

Comment: Please take the time to try this yourself and share your stylesheet. If you had ever run your input XML against an XSLT processor, you'd know that it is not well-formed.

Comment: @Mathias I have ran it and I forgot to include my xslt code. I edited the code above to take out sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is not clear how much generic the solution should be you could use following very simple stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="xlink">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <svg>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="svg:svg/svg:g" />
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="svg:svg/svg:g">
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="svg:g[1]" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="svg:text[3]" />
        </g>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for a simple and good solution. Just a minor point: `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` is added to the output elements.

Comment: @JirkaŠ. What does `svg:svg/svg:g` do specifically? I've looked everywhere online, but I can't understand what the `:` does in XSLT

Comment: In root element there is definition for namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` and this is asociated to the prefix "svg" (some kind of abbreviation). svg:svg means element "svg" from namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, svg:g means element "g" from namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`... (look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace ).And "svg:svg/svg:g" means element "g" with parent element "svg".

Answer (score 0):

For the selection of inner `g` elements, you can rely on the `position()` function. For the `text` elements, simply check whether there are any following siblings.

Also, note that it is essential to qualify the elements with the SVG namespace.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="svg:svg|svg:g[parent::svg:svg]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Match all g elements that are desendents of a g element -->  
<xsl:template match="svg:g[parent::svg:g]">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="svg:text">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::*)">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
   <g>
       <defs>
             <rect/>
       </defs>
       <clipPath/>
       <polygon/>
   </g>
  <text>Keep this text</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I cannot even get your XSLT code to run: I get the error `Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [<a href='xsltprocessor.transformtoxml'>xsltprocessor.transformtoxml</a>]: No stylesheet associated to this object`

Comment: I fixed it by adding xsl: to the closing stylesheet tag. @mathias your code only selects the last text tag, not all text tags that follow the 3rd inner `<g>` tag

Comment: I tried using: 
    <xsl:template match="svg:text">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="(following::svg:g[3])[parent::svg:g]">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: As far as I can see, my code did exactly what you stated in your question. Did you edit the question in the meantime? Last time I looked, there was only 1 "keep this text" in the expected output.

Comment: any elements in general or any `text` elements?

Comment: any elements in general. Sometimes I have `polygon` and `line` elements that follow the third `<g>` and I need to grab those elements as well.

Comment: I am _not_ willing to help you with this any further. You keep changing the requirements and XML input file and this makes it difficult for people wanting to help. Besides, it remains unclear what you really expect as output: You say you want to capture elements that **follow** the 3rd inner <g> tag, yet in your input XMl, there is a <polygon> element **inside** the 3rd inner <g>.